# GetListItems on Lists.asmx returns all items, not just the specified folder

Tags: 2007, list, web-services, folder

I'm trying to call the `Lists.asmx` webservice to retrieve only those items within a Folder named "Admin" in my SharePoint list. The webservice 'works' for me to some degree, but not as I expect.

The below soap returns only the items in the root folder, as expected.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"
                      xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <listName>{FBFB9086-58A5-4BFE-BAEC-615085147059}</listName>
            <viewName/>
            <rowLimit>1000</rowLimit>
            <webID/>
        </GetListItems>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I found the `QueryOptions` parameter in the proxy which injects a node into the soap request, as below:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"
                      xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <listName>{FBFB9086-58A5-4BFE-BAEC-615085147059}</listName>
            <viewName/>
            <rowLimit>1000</rowLimit>
            <queryOptions>
                <QueryOptions xmlns="">
                    <Folder>Admin</Folder>
                </QueryOptions>
            </queryOptions>
            <webID/>
        </GetListItems>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Instead of returning only those items in the "Admin" Folder, or even *including* those items, this request actually returns all items in all folders and subfolders with a recursive listing. This meets my need by returning the "Admin" items, but it is less than ideal because there are a large number of items.

Am I calling the webservice incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<Folder>` element should contain the full folder name including the RootFolder so it should be something like:

```
<Folder>Lists/MyList/Admin</Folder>
```